# Is it possible to do a join on a user-calculated/custom SQL view column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**This is for SQL Server**

So I have a SQL view where I manually define the values of a custom column via a CASE statement. Let's call the column name `StatusID`.

Now, I have a mapping table which holds a `StatusID` and `Description`. Let's call the table `dbo.StatusMapping`. Is it possible to do a join on `StatusMapping.StatusID` and my custom view column "`StatusID`" so that I can obtain the `Description` so that I can add it to my view?

Example code:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(a.OverallID),
    CASE
        WHEN a.IsTrue is null THEN 1 ELSE 2
    END AS StatusID, --This is what I'm trying to join my table on
    b.Description
FROM dbo.[MainTable] as a
JOIN dbo.[StatusMapping] as b on b.StatusID = StatusID --This is where it fails. "Invalid column name 'StatusID'"
```

Comment: Is it SQL Server or MySQL? And yes, it is possible theoretically. You should provide sample data and expected results though for getting a concrete answer. You normally join your view with the StatusMapping table on the StatusID field.

Comment: You can, in SQL Server, create a schema-bound indexed view that will persist the value of your computed column PROVIDING THE ENTIRE VIEW IS DETERMINISTIC (no outer joins, no group-bys, and several other restrictions). You can then EFFICIENTLY join on the column, providing the referencing query or view uses the WITH(NOEXPAND) hint. You can join on it without all this, but it's grossly inefficient and shouldn't be tried if the table will hold a lot of rows.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri Sorry, should have specified. This is for SQL Server. I added some very simple sample code to the OP

Comment: Did you try linking them and got an error? The only issue I'll see with this is that since your View.StatusID is defined by a CASE statement, your ID character type may not always match the statusMapping.StatusID

Comment: @Daath you should remove the 'mysql' tag from your question. It's a completely different product.

Comment: What effect would you like to produce with `DISTINCT` around `a.OverallID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options to do this join:

- **Repeat the expression for the computed column in the `where` clause** - this is not ideal, because the same expression is repeated, or
- **Use a common table expression** - this will work with SQL Server, but will not work in MySQL and other RDBMS which do not support CTE, or
- **Make a nested `select` with a table alias** - this lets you avoid repetition.

Here is an example of how to use nested `select`:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(x.OverallID),
    x.StatusID,
    b.Description
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.OverallID,
        CASE
            WHEN a.IsTrue is null THEN 1 ELSE 2
        END AS StatusID
    FROM dbo.[MainTable] as a
) AS x
JOIN dbo.[StatusMapping] as b on b.StatusID = x.StatusID
```

**Note:** I am not sure of the purpose of `DISTINCT` around `a.OverallID` in your original query. I copied it mechanically into the query, but good chances are that it is going to be unnecessary, or you would need to replace it with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you! This was the approach I ended up using and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the entire case statement in the JOIN.  Keep an eye on performance.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
        ( a.OverallID ) ,
        CASE WHEN a.IsTrue IS NULL THEN 1
             ELSE 2
        END AS StatusID ,
        b.Description
FROM    dbo.[MainTable] AS a
        JOIN dbo.[StatusMapping] AS b ON b.StatusID = CASE WHEN a.IsTrue IS NULL
                                                           THEN 1
                                                           ELSE 2
                                                      END
```

Comment: Or write a sub-query in the `FROM` clause, so you don't have to write the `CASE` twice.

Answer (score 1):

You could query the first table and calculate the StatusID in a subquery, and then join the result to table b.

```
SELECT a.OverallID
    , a.StatusID
    , b.Description
FROM (
    SELECT mt.OverallID
        , CASE WHEN a.IsTrue IS NULL THEN 1 
            ELSE 2 
          END AS [StatusID]
) a
    JOIN dbo.[StatusMapping] AS b ON (b.StatusID = a.StatusID)
```